# Problem trying to translate "+" into character +

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm having a problem trying to convert a character into a string in Xcode.  Here's my code...

```
NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  %@  %@ = %@", inputOne.text, sign.text, inputTwo.text, answer.text];
```

`self.sign.text` is supposed to return either  a "+", "-", "*", or "/", which it does.  However, I'm trying to have the user post one of these back into facebook via the app.  All but the "+" sign will load as a string when they post it to their wall.  I don't understand how to get the "+" to show.

I'm guessing that this gets lost since the "+" has a different meaning in javascript. How can I make it a string character in my `NSString` so that it accepts when posting.  Hope this made sense.

Comment: It could help to see also the code around that line. It's difficult to say what you are doing wrong without to see the code.

Comment: Sounds like a JavaScript issue. Javascript should have an escape character.

Comment: I'm trying to publish feeds to facebook.  The \+ key didn't work.

http://github.com/facebook/facebook-iphone-sdk

Look at the section there on Publishing Feed Stories.  I need to it to show this "1/2 + 1/2 = 1 or 1/1".  That's just a sample, but I want it to show the plus sign.

Answer (score 0):

I know you can put a quotation mark into a textView by placing a "\" before the quotation. This may work with a "+" sign as well. So the string would look something like this:

```
@"This is a plus sign \+ in a textView"
```

Which would return

```
This is a plus sign + in a textView
```

Comment: I'm trying to publish feeds to facebook.  The \+ key didn't work.

http://github.com/facebook/facebook-iphone-sdk

Look at the section there on Publishing Feed Stories.  I need to it to show this "1/2 + 1/2 = 1 or 1/1".  That's just a sample, but I want it to show the plus sign.

Answer (score 0):

Sending "+" over the net (e.g. in GET or, I think, POST) will convert "+" into a space character. To fix, you need to escape the "+" using "%2B".

Comment: You're still getting a space? Uh, how about %252B? That's "%" encoded plus 2B which becomes "%2B" which is "+"... Without digging into the framework, or seeing what your results look like, I can only guess away. :)

Comment: I figured it out.  It was %%2B.  I had to use double percentages. Thanks for the help guys :)